# Can't get jscrollpane to work with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jscrollpane

I'm having trouble getting the jscrollpane installed on a WordPress site. After doing some research, I tried the following but still no luck:

- double-checked that all links to .js
  files in my head are correct
- added the jscrollpane styles to my
  main stylesheet
- replaced the $ with jQuery on
  document.ready
- styled the .scroll-pane class with a
  height and overflow: auto

Here's my beta site: http://bradeller.com/sid/

Answer (score 1):

check whether you are inserting the div you want to be scroll pane into a not-so-wide div, therefore you can´t see the scroll bar, because the styles applied to scroll-pane are not as wide.

in width:100%, change to 100px, to make a test.